# Method called multiple times, instead of once

Tags: knockout.js

I have an edit method that is called when a row is clicked, to setup the information for edit (focus call, select call for easy input)... everything works fine without a call to the next edit (when a person reaches the last element in the row, I search the observable array for the next element... if there is one, it moves to the next element by calling the same method again).

The issue is, when this method is called, it stacks the requests in memory and every consecutive call into action. I know on jquery methods you can call the unbind method to release former calls to the same method, not sure what the best methodology for doing this for a knockout recursive function would be.

Any suggestions?

Here is a fiddle: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GmZjF/3/)

The call on line 51,

```
self.editItem(self.items()[index + 1]);
```

is recursive call that calls editItem to the next item on the list... there is an alert on line 26 that is called when the editItem method runs showing the difference in the runs. If you click on a row, and click on any other rows, it works fine, selects properly, and such... but if you tab when you are on the final field on the right (when it selects the next available item), it begins to stack.

Comment: Please provide an example of your bindings/called methods or issue recreated at jsfiddle. It's kinda difficult to help without looking at code.

Comment: I am working on it, will take some abstraction of some code to get it coded in jsfiddle, figured I'd post to see if anyone had a similar problem previously.

Comment: Added fiddle to show the issue on more simplified example, you could very well delete lines 28-37 as well to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use delegation method `.live` here because every time `editItem` called new keydown callback is added to the stack of earlier callbacks.

So just two things to be changed:

```
// change .live('keydown', ...) to .keydown(...) or .bind('keydown', ...)
$('#itemDescriptionEdit').keydown(function (e) {

    // ...

    // and return false at the end of callback to stop event propagation
    return false;
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ostgals/GmZjF/4/